# can Linux Bash search for file every 60 seconds and execute file commands? how would I do this?

Tags: bash

Basically I want to do something like this from bash.
 if a file exists in a directory rename,move,whatever 
 if it doesn't exist loop every 60 seconds:

```
# Create ~/bin
cd ~/
if dir ~/bin does not exist
then mkdir ~/bin

#!/bin/bash

# Create ~/blahhed && ~/blahs
if dir ~/blahhed does not exist
then mkdir ~/blahhed

if dir ~/blahs does not exist
then mkdir ~/blahs

# This will copy a file from ~/blahhed to  ~/blahs
if ~/blahhed/file exists
then mv ~/blahhed/file ~/blahs/file
rm ~/blahhed/file
else loop for 60s  

# This appends the date and time
# to the end of the file name
date_formatted=$(date +%m_%d_%y-%H,%M,%S)
if ~/blahs/file does exist
then mv ~/blahs/file ~/blahs/file.$date_formatted
rm ~/blahs/file
else loop for 60s
```

Ok Ive rewritten it like this am I on the right track here?

```
# Create ~/bin
cd ~/
if [! -d ~/bin]; then
mkdir ~/bin
if [ -d ~/bin]; then

#!/bin/bash

# Create ~/blahhed && ~/blahs 
if [! -d ~/blahhed]; then
mkdir ~/blahhed

if [! -d ~/blahs]; then
mkdir ~/blahs

# This will copy a file from ~/blahhed to  ~/blahs
while if [ -d  ~/blahhed/file]; then
do
mv ~/blahhed/file ~/blahs/file
rm ~/blahhed/file
continue

# This appends the date and time
# to the end of the file name
date_formatted=$(date +%m_%d_%y-%H,%M,%S)
if [! -d ~/blahs/file]; then
mv ~/blahs/file ~/blahs/file.$date_formatted
rm ~/blahs/file
sleep 60 seconds
```

Comment: Which particular part do you need help with? When you research checking if a directory exists in bash, or looping in bash, what results did you find, and what specific questions do you have about those pages?

Comment: do I need to add a sleep 60s function to this I want it running in the background infinitely and to break the loop up to save on cpu.

Comment: That doesn't answer any of my questions.

Comment: I found obfuscation thats why Im here... The question is simple and the answer is simple if you know anything about bash, loops, timing, and file searching from bash...

Comment: Ok here are some more obvious questions. Are my if,then,else statements syntactically correct(would you use if,else or would you use while,do?)? Are my loops and timing syntactically correct for an infinite search loop of a folder broken into 60 second increments?

Comment: This is my first bash script.

Comment: I guess my point is, you have some bits of pseudocode in your script. "if dir ~/bin does not exist", for instance. My suggestion is to google "how to check if a directory exists in bash" and see if you can figure out how to convert that pseudocode into real code. If you have trouble with that we're here to help, but you should take a stab at it yourself first. The same thing goes for "loop every 60 seconds in bash" or similar search queries. Hope that helps!

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What are your motivations for writing such a script? My answer may provide existing alternatives! Please edit your question to improve it!

Comment: I gave you the *exact google search terms* to use. @Basile's written an excellent, comprehensive answer. This is the best we can do with the question as written.

Comment: I want to drag and drop a file into a folder and have it automatically renamed and moved to a different directory.

Comment: I want that folder to be scanned every 60 seconds for a file named file then once the operation is complete and file is moved and renamed the non-appended file is deleted....

Comment: A word of warning: Files can appear before the process writing them is done.

Comment: so should I another sleep before deletion?

Comment: is there a wait function?

Comment: You edited script is wrong. Missing spaces around `]`; wrong `while`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [watch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) which is able to run a program or script every *N* seconds.

To run some script every few minutes (not seconds) - or every few hours or days, use some [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entries. To run it at some given (relative or absolute) time, consider [at(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at) (which you might use with some [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) in your shell terminal, etc...).

However, to execute commands when a file exists or changes, you might use [make(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/make.1.html) (which you could run from `watch`); that command is configurable in a `Makefile` (see documentation of [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/))

And if you really care about file appearing or changing (and doing something on such changes), consider using [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) based facilities, e.g. `incrond` with [incrontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab)

To test existence of directories or files, use [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html) often spelt as a `[` , e.g.

```
## test in a script if directory ~/foo/ exist
if [ -d ~/foo/ ]; then
   echo the directory foo exists
fi
```

<sup>Spaces are important above. You could use `[ -d "$HOME/foo/" ]`</sup>

It may look that you want to mimick [logrotate(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate). See also [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) library function and [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) command.

To debug your bash script, start it (-see [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) & [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) for details- temporarily, while debugging) with

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
```

and make your `foo.sh` script executable with `chmod a+x foo.sh`

To stop execution of some script for some seconds, use [sleep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sleep.1.html)

The [mkdir(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html) command accepts `-p` (and then won't create a directory if it already exists). [mv(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mv.1.html) has also many options (including for backup).

To search some files in a file tree, use [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html). To search some content inside files, use [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html). I also like [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/)

Read also [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) & (if coding in C ...) [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and also the documentation of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) (e.g. for shell builtins and control statements).

Did you consider using some [revision control system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) like [git](http://git-scm.org/) ? It is useful to manage the evolution of source files (including shell scripts)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen solutions similar to what you are asking, but using crontab with `find -mmin 1` which will search for any files with a modtime <= 60 seconds within specified location.

Something along these lines (untested):

```
$ -> vi /tmp/file_finder.sh

# Add the following lines

#!/bin/bash

find /path/to/check -mmin 1 -type -f | while read fname; do
    echo "$fname"
done

# Change perms
$ -> chmod 755 /tmp/file_finder.sh

$ -> crontab -e
* * * * * /tmp/file_finder.sh
```

With the above, you have now setup the cron to run every minute, and kick off a script that will search given directory for files with a modtime <= 60 seconds (new or updated).

Caveat: You should look for files with a mod time up to 5 minutes, that way you don't consider a file which may still be in the process of being written too.

Comment: Ok I guess what I really need is the propper syntax for starting and stopping a loop and a method for producing that loop every 60 seconds.

Comment: What did you end up going with?

Answer (score 1):

I think you answered yourself (kind of)

Some suggestions:

1- use a while loop and at the end add `sleep 60`

2- write your procedure in a file (ex.; test1)
and then

```
watch -n 60 ./test1
```

Comment: Im not sure watch is what I want that is only for generating toast messages or ah rather terminal output right?

Comment: Basically I want this script to scrape a folder so that when a file is placed there this automated process happens...But I only want to scrape every 60 seconds to save on cpu...

Comment: With `watch` you can re run your script (after every specified second). dumping the result on terminal is up to you.
So, for solving the problem, 1- write a while loop, 2-check for any file inside it (and do the processes that you want, in the case that file exist).3- sleep for 60 `sleep 60` at the end of the while loop. In this case, you will check for every 60 seconds.